# FullStory with React-Native n.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-router

Windows 10

React-Native stack

"react": "16.8.3",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",

"react-fullstory": "^1.3.0",

I'm attempting to run https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fullstory

from fullstory.com on my react-native application, but using their script nor react libraries seem to help. I've tried this code and received the error that fullstack doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import FullStory from 'react-fullstory';
  public render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Routing
          // persistenceKey={navigationPersistenceKey}
          renderLoadingExperimental={() => <LoadingPage />}
        />
        <ToastMessage ref={this.toastRef} />
        <FullStory org={'My_Id'} debug={true} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: n.getElementsByTagName is not a function. (In 'n.getElementsByTagName(t)',
'n.getElementsByTagName' is undefined)

This error is located at:
in FullStory (at App.tsx:90)
in AppWrapper (created by Connect(AppWrapper))
in Connect(AppWrapper) (at App.tsx:119)
in ThemeProvider (at App.tsx:118)
in Provider (at App.tsx:117)
in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

node_modules\react-fullstory\dist\index.js:97:33 in
node_modules\react-fullstory\dist\index.js:282:24 in FullStory
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: I did not. It turned out most of the tools I tried don't even work natively for both ios and android. I'm pretty sure that's why I gave up on this option.

Comment: Thank. What path have you chosen?

Comment: I ended up using logrocket which works great for web, and will possibly support mobile with react native one day!

Comment: Hey @Urasquirrel Would you share you experience with FullStory&ReactNative :) ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I didn't continue with FullStory and have since used Logrocket with many other projects. I'm not sure I'll ever use FullStory unless it pulls through with React and ReactNative Support.

Comment: Thank you @Urasquirrel for taking the time to share your experience with us ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is because Fullstory is currently geared more towards use within a web application that runs in the browser. Since React Native applications don't run in a browser, that would explain the error you're receiving.

Although their docs are hard a bit hard to find, Fullstory does support Native Mobile applications:

- [Getting Started with iOS Recording](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042772333-Getting-Started-with-iOS-Recording)
- [Getting Started with Android Recording](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040596093-Getting-Started-with-Android-Recording)

With Native Mobile support, it looks like Fullstory is actively working on adding support for React Native as well.

Within their [Github OSS organization](https://github.com/fullstorydev), there are two repositories related to React Native:

- https://github.com/fullstorydev/fullstory-react-native
- https://github.com/fullstorydev/fullstory-babel-plugin-react-native

My team is actively looking to add Fullstory to our React Native application, so I'd be happy to share any findings should they come up.